# DataContractJsonSerializer not serializing properly

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to serialize some data which contains an observable collection of objects and write it into a text tile. My output is [] and I do now know where I have made a mistake.

my object code

```
public class ObjectList : ObservableCollection<string>, INotify...
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> ObjectListInstance = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public string Name;

    ... get set methods & property changed method
}
```

my IO code

```
using (Stream newStream = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("file.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
{
      DataContractJsonSerializer newDataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<ObjectList>));
      newDataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject(newStream, ObjectList);
}
```

my code stub

```
    ObjectList newObjectList = new ObjectList();
        newObjectList.Name = "AAA NAME";


        newObjectList.ObjectListInstance.Add("ITEM 1");
        newObjectList.ObjectListInstance.Add("ITEM 2");

        bool status = await IOClass.IO.WriteCategory(newObjectList);
```

Comment: the objectlist object? the objectlist object contains an observablecollection of strings and a string. can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a class that *is* both a collection and has additional properties to be serialized.  However, you *can* have a class that *contains* a list and has additional properties, which is what I think you are trying to do here.  To make it work you will need to make some adjustments to your code:

1. Your `ObjectList` should not inherit from `ObservableCollection<T>` (or any other list type)
2. You must mark your class with `[DataContract]`, and mark the properties/fields you want to be serialized with `[DataMember]`.
3. When you create your `DataContractJsonSerializer` instance, pass to the constructor the top-level type you want to serialize.  In your case, this should be `ObjectList`, not `ObservableCollection<ObjectList>`.
4. When you call `WriteObject` on the serializer, the second parameter should be the object instance you are serializing, not a `Type`.

Here is the corrected class:

```
[DataContract]
public class ObjectList
{
    [DataMember]
    public ObservableCollection<string> ObjectListInstance = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;
}
```

Here is the corrected serialization code:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer newDataContractJsonSerializer = 
                           new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObjectList));

newDataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject(newStream, newObjectList);
```

With these changes you should get the following JSON output:

```
{"Name":"AAA NAME","ObjectListInstance":["ITEM 1","ITEM 2"]}
```

Comment: Adding in the [DataContract] and [DataMember] works!

Comment: May I just ask why am I able to perform the serialization successfully for just one observable collection <string> without the use of the [datacontract] and [datamember]? What is the difference between these two examples?

Comment: One is a list and the other isn't.  If it's a list, you can't use the [DataContract] attribute, and if it isn't a list, you have to use the attribute.